# How to list directory files in SFTP using parallel-ssh?

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, libssh2, parallel-ssh

I have the following code which successfully connects to an SFTP server and copies a file from remote to local.

But how can I list directory contents?

Running the command 'ls' fails

```
    import pssh.clients, pssh.utils

    pssh.utils.enable_logger(pssh.utils.logger)
    hosts  = OPT['ftp']['host']
    client = pssh.clients.SSHClient(hosts, port=OPT['ftp']['port'], user=OPT['ftp']['user'], password=OPT['ftp']['pass'])  # ParallelSSHClient SSHClient

    cmds = client.copy_remote_file('1223d_ca.zip', '/dev/shm/hi.zip')

    # cmds = client.run_command('ls')  # fails
```

with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./app.py", line 1594, in <module>
    cmds = client.run_command('ls')
  File "/home/da/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pssh/clients/base/single.py", line 555, in run_command
    channel = self.execute(_command, use_pty=use_pty)
  File "/home/da/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pssh/clients/native/single.py", line 301, in execute
    self._eagain(channel.execute, cmd)
  File "/home/da/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pssh/clients/native/single.py", line 349, in _eagain
    return self._eagain_errcode(func, LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/da/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pssh/clients/base/single.py", line 576, in _eagain_errcode
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "ssh2/channel.pyx", line 79, in ssh2.channel.Channel.execute
  File "ssh2/utils.pyx", line 174, in ssh2.utils.handle_error_codes
ssh2.exceptions.ChannelRequestDenied
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it using `ssh2-python`

```
import socket,ssh2.session  # ssh2-python is a low-level wrapper around C libssh2

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((OPT['ftp']['host'], OPT['ftp']['port']))
sess = ssh2.session.Session()
sess.handshake(sock)
sess.userauth_password(OPT['ftp']['user'], OPT['ftp']['pass'])

sftp = sess.sftp_init()  # https://ssh2-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sftp.html

# with sftp.open('1223d_ca.zip', ssh2.sftp.LIBSSH2_FXF_READ, ssh2.sftp.LIBSSH2_SFTP_S_IRUSR) as fp:  # opendir()
#   for size,data in fp:
#       print(size,data)

with sftp.opendir('/') as fp:
    for size,buf,attrs in fp.readdir():
        print(size,buf,attrs)

sock.close()
```